# How can I change label color in Java?

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, jlabel

I have set of labels in LinkList call "l" and I need to change the background colors of those labels. I need to put 2 secconds gap between each color change so I tried to use repaint method as follows but it doesn't give me the required result. Please can some one give me a solution for this problem ?

```
    public static void changeColor(LinkedList l,JFrame f){

    for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
        try {
            final JLabel xx = (JLabel) l.get(i);
            xx.setBackground(Color.red);
            f.repaint();
            xx.setText("B");
            System.out.println(i);
            new thread().run();
            xx.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
            xx.setText("A");
            f.repaint();

            } catch (Exception ex) {
               Logger.getLogger(TestView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: dont call repaint in application code - most of times, even if it seems to be a solution there's a deeper problem somewhere else

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[JLabel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) is by defalut `non-Opaque`, even you setBackGround(whatever), then without definitions for `myLabel.setOpaque(true);` isn't `JLabel'area` colorized, another way is using [CustomPaint](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html) with overide `paintComponetn()`, for example

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LabelBackGround {

    private JFrame frame;

    public LabelBackGround() {
        JLabel lblWest = new JLabel();
        lblWest.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 150));
        lblWest.setOpaque(true);
        lblWest.setBackground(Color.red);
        JLabel lblEast = new JLabel();
        lblEast.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 150));
        lblEast.setOpaque(true);
        lblEast.setBackground(Color.red);
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new CustomColoredComponents(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(new CustomColoredComponents(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.add(lblWest, BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.add(lblEast, BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocation(100, 100);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                LabelBackGround gridBadFrame = new LabelBackGround();
            }
        });
    }
}

class CustomColoredComponents extends JLabel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 20);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 30);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        int margin = 10;
        Dimension dim = getSize();
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.fillRect(margin, margin, dim.width - margin * 2, dim.height - margin * 2);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

and void that you posted has too much problem with [Concurency in Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), then all output from `BackGroung Tasks` to the GUI must be wrapped into `invokeLater()` and last code lines in you code block would be `revalidate ()` and `repaint()` for fill `JComponents` inside visible Container

Comment: Yes I have already change setOpaque() value as true. But it doesn't give the solution.

Comment: I edited my post, that's another issue, and I think that nothing to do with setBackGroung for JLabel

Answer (score 1):

Three things:
1) Setting the background colour by using setBackground should result in it repainting itself with the new colour without a call to repaint (assuming it is opaque).
2) I would suggest using `javax.swing.Timer` class for this. Make sure you know the difference between this and the `java.util.Timer` class.
3) Calling setBackground(null) should restore the "default colour".